# qt 5.7 + Xcode 8.1 + os x El Capitan - could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

I'm new to Qt and have just installed it on my mac running OS X El Capitan. But unfortunately I'm getting `could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'` when trying to run any example app.

I spent some time trying to find solution, but nothing works. I tried changing qdevice.pri according to the SDK version that I found in Xcode (MacOSX.sdk and MacOSX10.12.sdk link) but it didn't help.

My gcc settings are:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I'm running OS X El Capitan, Xcode 8.1, Qt 5.7.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems like I found the reason of getting errors. In my `Xcode's -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools` there was no SDK selected. I have selected Xcode 8.1 and it seems to work ok now. Hope it won't be other problems.

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer here in SO if it solved your issue.

Comment: I solved this issue by simply opening Xcode and clicking 'Agree'. I can't explain why that may have worked.

Comment: I just upgraded to Catalina and got "Failed to resolve SDK path for 'iphoneos'" when running cmake to create an XCode configuration, your solution applied there as well.