# wchar.h file not found - Xcode 9.0 breaks Qt Creator - old fixes do not work

Tags: c++, xcode, qt

Background install of Xcode 9.0 this morning breaks all my Qt Creator builds with: 'wchar.h' file not found - all previous advice fails to resolve...
e.g. [macOS 'wchar.h' File Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found)
All help and advice much appreciated

Comment: - all today auto-updated Xcode 9, Cmd line tools & Safari v11 
- this also breaks the open source Qt installer which gets stuck in a loop asking for Xcode 5.0 (!?)

Comment: - FIX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513456/qt-5-7-xcode-8-1-os-x-el-captain-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools -> select SDK

Answer (score 0):

a) Check software updates to ensure you have also updated the command line tools.

b) check that the installation is correct:

```
$ cat > nod.cpp
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
}
^D

$ c++ nod.cpp
```

c) If that's all good, you probably need reconfigure and rebuild dependencies using the new toolchain.

automake, cmake, etc deduce full path names and embed them in makefiles and project files.